# example of an $\ell_1$-saturated Banach space without an unconditional basis

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Giorgos Petsoulas, in his paper "A class of $\ell^p$ saturated Banach spaces," has constructed for each $1<p<\infty$ a space $\mathfrak{X}_p$ which is complementably $\ell_p$-saturated but admits no unconditional basis.  I was wondering if such an example has been proved for the case $p=1$.

I have managed to construct a space which is complementably $\ell_1$-saturated but admits no symmetric basis.  However, it does admit a subsymmetric one---in particular, an unconditional one.  I was going to adapt my technique to see if I could also kill off unconditionality.  But, it would be more motivating to me to know whether this has been done before ; )

Just to be clear, when I ask for a space $X$ to be "complementably $\ell_p$-saturated" I mean that for every infinite-dimensional closed subspace $Y$ of $X$ we can find a continuous linear projection $P:X\to X$ such that $PX\subseteq Y$ and $PX\cong\ell_p$.

Thank you!

Comment: Take the $\ell_1$ sum of any sequence of finite dimensional spaces whose GL constants tend to infinity.

Comment: J. Lindenstrauss showed $\ell_1$ has a subspace with no unconditional basis in *On a certain subspace of $\ell_1$*, Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci., 12,  539-542, 1964.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Szankowski (Subspaces without the approximation property. Israel J. Math. 30 (1978), no. 1-2, 123–129) for each $1\le p<2$ constructed a subspace $X$ of $\ell_p$ without the approximation property and thus without an unconditional basis. On the other hand, as a subspace of $\ell_p$, $1\le p<\infty$, the space $X$ is complementably $\ell_p$-saturated.